# visual studio (2015) Task Runner "Project Open" bound task is launched twice when open solution

Tags: visual-studio, gulp, gulp-watch, task-runner-explorer

I have a "watch" task that bound it to "project open" binding . but when open the solution , it is run twice ... my solution includes these projects:

- Controllers
- EFRepository
- Infrastructure
- Model
- ReportLibrary
- WebUI
- Design

and my watch task is:

```
gulp.task("watch-templates", [], function () {
var config = {
    baseDir: "WebUI/Templates",
    files: [
        // includes:
        "WebUI/Templates/**/*.html",
        // excludes:
        "!WebUI/Templates/**/*.min.html"
    ]
};
return gulp.watch(config.files, ["Build-templates"]);
```

});

thanks for time.

Comment: Hi! I think that, when you open the solution, multiple files are generated / uploaded, such as *.sln *.proj and others, maybe that's what's causing the "run twice" try to limit the watch on the file types you want. Could it be the problem? I never tried it with Visual Studio Projects, but that's something that I will have to do soon.

Comment: Thank for reply . I have thought sth like that but I have 7 project in my solution .you can see my watch task in question (I edited).

Comment: humm.. I wonder if, Visual Studio run his own tasks (probably yes) to update references like bundle packages, sort like you can achieve using wiredep or gulp-inject and that's what is causing it. Try to look at the last change datetime of the files using explorer and "see" if it changes upon open project.

Comment: actually no . files didnt change from last time that I open the solution .(if they changed I should see them in my "pending changes "part)

Comment: Still happens when task runner is in auto hide mode. VS 2015 Update 3

Comment: **This still happens in Visual Studio 2017.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been experiencing the same problem.

I found these two issues raised with MS but they seem to have limited the scope of the issue to when the Task Runner Explorer is set to auto-hide.

I am facing this issue regardless of how my Task Runner Explorer Panel is positioned.

[Original Closed Ticket](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1571481/task-runner-explorer-project-open-bound-task-is-launched-twice-when-vs2015-rtm-is-opened-and-tre-window-state-is-auto-hide)

[Resolved Ticket](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1768982/task-runner-explorer-project-open-bound-task-is-launched-twice-when-vs2015-rtm-is-opened-and-tre-window-state-is-auto-hide)

MS have said that Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 RTM solves the issue mentioned in these tickets but I haven't tried updating myself.  Hopefully it will also solve the issue we are both encountering.

Answer (score 1):

Just got it in vs 2019 too... but looks like version 16.2 will fix it.
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/526923/task-runner-explorer-calls-task-two-times-on-proje.html